Pivot Hinge for Glass Panel
I have a pane of 6mm toughened glass that is 2 m high, 0.7 m wide and weighs 21 kg. I've been trying to find some pivot hinges that can handle this glass and also pivot at the corner of the glass. All the pivot hinges I've found so far that pivot at the corner of the glass cannot handle a piece of glass this big. The attached image is an example of the biggest corner pivot hinge I could find. But it will only handle a 12.7 kg, 508 mm wide piece of glass. Pivot hinges for bigger pieces of glass don't appear to have been designed to pivot at the corner of the glass, like a frameless glass shower door for example.
The pivot hinge is positioned some distance from the corner, resulting in the corner of the glass pivoting into the internal space as the door is opened. I cannot have this happen, so I need it to pivot at the corner. I was planning on just fabricating my own pivot hinge out of 3mm steel. It is essentially just a U shape piece of steel with a small rod welded on. The rod just sits in a hole in the frame of the door. One in the bottom corner and one in the top corner. I'm just not sure how big of a hinge I would need to make to handle glass this big and heavy and have no idea how to calculate that from an engineering point of view. Does anyone have any ideas?


You can't do that with 6mm glass. Max height for a corner hinge on 6mm glass is about 24 inches and max width is 15 inches. You need a fully framed glass door, or at least double the thickness of glass. https://www.google.com/search?q=glass+door+hinge+cutouts&rlz=1C1RXQR_enUS1086US1087&oq=glass+door+hinge+cutouts&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIHCAEQIRigATIHCAIQIRigATIHCAMQIRigAdIBCTE0MDM3ajBqN6gCALACAA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:e8f024a7,vid:WrE-tvjHxkU,st:0

That's not true. I have found corner hinges designed for 6mm glass that can be up to 20 inches wide and I have a cabinet here next to me with corner hinges that uses 4mm glass and it is 62 inches high. These aren't things I've made, but have bought from shops, like Ikea. I was just hoping to get it a bit bigger by using 6mm glass instead of 4mm glass and fabricating a bigger hinge.
